# How the shape is (3 2 1) | Numpy |

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am learning numpy , have a question in my mind not able to clearly visualise from where this 1 as come in shape

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ [[1],[56]] , [[8],[98]] ,[[89],[62]] ])
np.shape(a)
```

The output is printed as : `(3 ,2 , 1)`

Will be appreciated if you could represent in diagrammatic / image format
What actually the 1 means in output

Comment: You can convert `a` to NumPy and print it to get better visualization. Your `a` has 3 rows `[ [...], [...], [...] ]` and each row has 2 elements i.e. each `[...]` is `[ [---], [---] ]`, now each `[---]` has 1 element i.e each `[---]` -> `[*]`. This would be your final array of shape `(3, 2, 1)` -> `[ [ [*], [*] ], [ [*], [*] ], [ [*],[*] ] ]`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, that last 1 is because every number in `a` has brackets around it.

Formally, it's the length of your "last" or "innermost" dimension. You can take your first two dimensions and arrange `a` as you would a normal matrix, but note that each element itself has brackets around it - each element is itself an array:

```
[[ [1] [56]]
 [ [8] [98]]
 [[89] [62]]]
```

If you add an element to each innermost-array, making that third `shape` number get larger, it's like stacking more arrays behind this top one in 3d, where now the corresponding elements in the "behind" array are in the same innermost array as the "front" array.

Equivalently, instead of considering the *first* two indices to denote the regular flat matrices, you can think of the *back* two making the flat matrices. This is how numpy does it: try printing out an array like this: `x = np.random.randint(10, size = (3,3,3))`.  Along the first dimension, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are printed after each other, and each one individually is formatted like a 3x3 matrix. Then the second index corresponds to the *rows* of each individual matrix, and the third index corresponds to the *columns*. Note that when you print `a`, there's only one column  displayed - its third dimension has size 1. You can play with the definition of `x` to see more what's going on (change the numbers in the `size` argument).

An alright example of visualizing a 3d array this way is this image, found on the Wikipedia page for the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol):

[image: visualization of 3d Levi-Civita symbols]

Don't worry too much about what the Levi-Civita symbol actually *is* - just note that here, if it were a numpy array it would have shape `(3,3,3)` (like the `x` I defined above). You use three indices to specify each element, *i*, *j*, and *k*. *i* tells you the depth (blue, red, or green), *j* tells you the row, and *k* tells you the column. When numpy prints, it just lists out blue, red, then green in order.